# JavaScript/Jquery in Visual Studio, Any Intellisense? Any Help for writing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio

I have been working in Visual Studio 2010, in asp.net, i am using Jquery for posting and receiving results and it works perfectly, but the issue is, when we make a JavaScript file in Visual Studio, there is no Intellisense (Drop down Help while writing code) while working in it, and if error occurs, we have to go to Firefox error console to see errors, but is not there is helping support in Visual Studio 2010? Please let me know  if you know any Jquery or Javascript

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/08/jquery-1-4-1-intellisense-with-visual-studio.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...and in fact if you use nuget to get the latest jquery 1.6 http://nuget.org/List/Packages/jQuery
This includes the latest vsdoc.js file.

Answer (score 4):

[Everything you need to know about JavaScript intellisense in Visual Studio](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/21/vs-2008-javascript-intellisense.aspx).

[Here's an updated post that addresses JavaScript intellisense improvements/updates in Visual Studio 2010](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/08/javascript-intellisense-improvements-with-vs-2010.aspx).

[Here's a link to a vsdoc generator](http://damianedwards.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/jquery-vsdoc-file-generator/) by Damian Edwards (dev on the ASP.NET team). Use this to generate Visual Studio intellisense docs for any version of jQuery.