# javascript intellisense for visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

I am wondering if there is any way to get JavaScript Intellisense in Visual Studio.

It provides only a little help in Intellisense. I am writing code for jQuery.

```
function moverowup(row_img_btn_id) {
    $rowObj = $('#' + row_img_btn_id);
    var row = $rowObj.parents('tr:first');
    $prevRow = row.prev();
    if ($prevRow.is(".headerRow")) {
        // do nothing
    }
    else
        row.insertBefore(row.prev());
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript/Jquery in Visual Studio, Any Intellisense? Any Help for writing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814137/javascript-jquery-in-visual-studio-any-intellisense-any-help-for-writing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there might be other ways to do it but i found one here
http://blog.craigtp.co.uk/post/Javascript-jQuery-Intellisense-in-Visual-Studio-2012.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874692.aspx